# How to use a listenLatch if the receiver/listener is in a separate project

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I refer to [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/blob/master/spring-rabbit-confirms-returns/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/samples/confirms/SpringRabbitConfirmsReturnsApplication.java).

How a listenerLatch can be set in a separate Listener/Receiver project that the Sender can refer to determine whether the listener received the message?

Also in general how the Configuration can be shared between two different projects like Sender and Receiver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - the sender and receiver are independent.

You should test each component separately.